# Hovering over elliptic word to show original word in JB

Tags: android, hover, ellipsis

I have a requirement of flashing the original word for elliptic one(which is shorted because of space constraint around it) if there is hovering done by S-pen on the particular part of that screen.
I have the code of finding the hovering position and finding the elliptic word as well.
I want a sample code to pass the Exact word for the elliptic word so that I can show the original word once pen is pointing that particular position.
(Since its newly introduced in Android with JB I am not finding much help from google..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `PopupWindow`. Create a XML layout containing `TextView`, inflate it within the pop-up window (or just create it through constructor).

```
public class HoverPopup extends PopupWindow {

    public HoverPopup(Context context, String text) {
        //...
        TextView textView = (TextView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.hover_popup, null);
        textView.setText(text);
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

S Pen event library initialization and the hover listener implementation

```
private final SPenEventLibrary mSPenEventLibrary = new SPenEventLibrary();
private final SPenHoverListener mSPenHoverListener = new SPenHoverListener() {

    private HoverPopup mHoverPopup;

    @Override           
    public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
            mHoverPopup = new HoverPopup(mContext, "Your text");
            mHoverPopup.showAsDropDown(view);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
            mHoverPopup.dismiss();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Do not forget to attach the S Pen hover listener to a view

```
mSPenEventLibrary.setSPenHoverListener(view, mSPenHoverListener);
```

Answer (score -1):

See [sample code of Spen SDK by Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/samples/20-samples-in-S-Pen-SDK-2-2-5)

Comment: Next time consider using 'edit' post option. The samples you linked to contains no information which are helpful to solve your problem.