# SPenHoverListener not working in GS4

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have tried the [S-Pen SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk) examples but none of the finger hover events are fired in GS4.  Most of the device built-in apps like Email, Video, Flipboard,... have the `AirView` feature working very well but when I implement the `S-Pen SDK AirView` in my app the events are not fired, even on the SDK examples. I took the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082235/hovering-over-elliptic-word-to-show-original-word-in-jb) SO post. Any idea why the built-in app work and the SDK apps don't work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by adding an `intent-filter` to the activity:

[Samsung hovering API with finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308986/samsung-hovering-api-with-finger)